# Iterating several lists item by item with Python

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

Using Python, say I have three lists like this:

```
list1 = ["ABC","JKL","STU"]
list2 = ["DEF", "MNO", "VWX"]
list3 = ["GHI", "PQR", "YZ0"]
```

I would like to loop the lists, so that the result would be a list like this:

```
result = ["ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO", "PQR", "STU", "VWX", "YZ0"]
```

I can make it work with a simple for-loop:

```
result = []

for i in range(3):
    result.append(list1[i])
    result.append(list2[i])
    result.append(list3[i])
```

Because the project I want to use this kind of approach includes much more lists than three, I thought using a bit more sophisticated way. I tried using `itertools.chain()` function, but it loops each list separately before moving to the next one:

```
result = []

for i in itertools.chain(list1, list2, list3):
    result.append(i)
```

Is there a way to make this work with `itertools.chain()` or with some other function?

Comment: `sum(zip(list1, list2, list3), tuple())`. Hey you all, I've just posted this as demonstration of possible "hack". It doesn't mean that it's good solution. Proper way to implement this is `list(chain.from_iterable(zip(list1, list2, list3)))`

Comment: Or using nested list comprehension: `[i for t in zip(list1, list2, list3) for i in t]`

Comment: @Kolumbo Could you check if you have a typo in your expected output for `result`, the first "JKL" probably doesn't need to be there. (10 items in result list right now but should only be 9).

Comment: Google is your friend in finding the answer - https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-merge-two-or-more-lists/

Comment: I am not sure why the question got so heavily downvoted and closed. The question is not that unclear and the person asking has apparently tried `itertools.chain()`.

Comment: @lucas I think it was mainly the typo I mentioned above lol...

Answer (score -1):

use `numpy.hstack`

```
import numpy as np

list1 = ["ABC","JKL","STU"]
list2 = ["DEF", "MNO", "VWX"]
list3 = ["GHI", "PQR", "YZ0"]

np.hstack([list1, list2, list3]) 
# -> array(['ABC', 'JKL', 'STU', 'DEF', 'MNO', 'VWX', 'GHI', 'PQR', 'YZ0'], dtype='<U3')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
result = sum((list(e) for e in zip(list1, list2, list3)), [])
```

not the prettiest way. Still playing around. Problem is, that zip returns tuples and they cannot be summed up directly. Therefore, the extra generator to convert `e` from tuple to list.

Comment: Okay, others beat me to the punch and solved my issue better :)